# Removing most default objects and functions from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a stripped down sandbox for people to write JavaScript in. I do not want users to have features like `Reflect.defineProperty`, `eval` or `WebAssembly.Module`.

Currently the way I go about this is by going over [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects#standard_objects_by_category), and disabling the objects manually. i.e.

```js
globalThis = {};
eval = () => {};
etc..
```

I want to disable all default JavaScript features and manually re-enable/add them back when I need them. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know you can override default functions like this. Nice.

```js
var original = alert;
alert = function (str) {
  console.log(str)
}
alert(13)

// afterwards
alert = original;
alert(12)
```

Comment: Yup yup, we use this a lot in browser game hacking.

Comment: How? a game that you create or play?

Comment: In browser games made by others. They often use built in JavaScript functions to parse/modfiy data, so you can overwrite the built in functions to get ahold of them